# Alert on SCOM Monitoring failover

Tags: windows, alerts, scom

A synopsis of the problem:

Sometimes due to problems in the database server SCOM cannot access its DB and hence the monitoring stops. Which results in no alert messages being sent.

Is there a way for me to throw alert when the SCOM monitoring stops. A powershell script to throw a mail or someother method?

I cannot install any extra applications/tools than what is already there in a basic windows server installation.

Answer (score 2):

If powershell is installed on the RMS or RMSe then I would write a script that would check that the healthservice, cshost and omsdk services are running.  I would also try to identify a concrete event message that indicates that your SCOM environment has lost connectivity to the database; the OpsMgr log will surely show this but I can't recall one off the top of my head.

Take said script and schedule it to run every so often; say hourly or if you need to be more aggressive, every 15 minutes.

Of course the best thing to do is to figure out why your database tier keeps failing.